# How to add retries to Micronaut non-declarative http client

Tags: java, httpclient, micronaut, micronaut-client

Micronaut supports retry mechanism for http clients if we use it in a declarative client like this :

```
@Client("http://127.0.0.1:8200")
@Retryable(delay = "${retry-delay}", attempts = "${retry-attempts}")
@Header(name = "username", value = "password")

public interface SampleHttpClient {
    @Get(value = "/v1/kv/data/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    HttpResponse<String> getVaultSecret();
}
```

Here **retry-delay** and **retry-attempts** are read from configuration yaml file.

But I am **creating the http clients in my code on the fly** as show below. This is because I get the http client parameters(URL, retry properties, header etc) at runtime.

How can I add retry option to my http configuration here ?

```
HttpClient client = null;
var configuration = new ServiceHttpClientConfiguration("myId", null, 
                                  null, new DefaultHttpClientConfiguration());  
   
// how to add retry to http configuration here ???       

client = new DefaultHttpClient("http://127.0.0.1:8200", configuration);

var uri = UriBuilder.of("http://127.0.0.1:8200").path("/v1/kv/data/").build();
var request = HttpRequest.GET(uri).header("username","password");
var response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically in the background micronaut uses the [AOP](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#aopArch) Advice for retrying using [@Retryable](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/api/io/micronaut/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) annotation

So, you can basically move the logic into method and implement the logic to retry that method on exception and with delay.

```
@Retryable(attempts = "2", includes =[NullPointerException.class,..], delay= "1s")
public void clientCall() {

  client = new DefaultHttpClient("http://127.0.0.1:8200", configuration);

  var uri = UriBuilder.of("http://127.0.0.1:8200").path("/v1/kv/data/").build();
  var request = HttpRequest.GET(uri).header("username","password");
  var response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request);
}
```

You can also configure the values in `application.yml/application.properties` and use them in annotation

```
@Retryable(
attempts = "\${micronaut.http.services.get_core_item_graphql.retryAttempts}",
delay = "\${micronaut.http.services.get_core_item_graphql.retryDelay}")
```

Comment: Again the value of attempts is hardcoded. Here I should be able to set the value to attempts through java code.

Comment: you can configure them in properties file @shashank

Comment: In my case, they cannot be read from config file, I should read it from db and modify them at runtime. So I am looking at reflection APIs to change the value of annotation at runtime

Comment: "So I am looking at reflection APIs to change the value of annotation at runtime" - I don't expect that to work.  An approach that would work is using `@Retryable` and configuring a property source that reads config from the db.